# Check for available Windows Updates offline

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to check if Windows Updates are available without going online? I know there is the Windows Update Agent API and you can check offline by providing the wsusscn2.cab, but then I'd have to update this file regularly. I think there must be a way to check a file, the registry, WMI or something else to get the info if there are Windows Updates available.

The best solution I found so far is parsing the WindowsUpdate.log file, but I'm not really happy with that.

Thanks,
Achim

Comment: _"Is there a way to check if Windows Updates are available without going online?"_ - yeah, by checking the expired bit of each dll. As soon as they expire, an update will be available. - No, you cannot do this. The update server says which updates are available, how do you think you can figure this out without an update server? Why not just let Windows handle its updates itself, why do you want to intervene, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Windows already contacts the update server and checks for updates. I assume this information must be stored anywhere permanently as I can disconnect my computer from the Internet and after rebooting it still knows that there are updates to install. I want to check from my remote computer for updates without waiting for seconds until the update server gives me an answer (it doesn't kill me but I think there must be a way to get this information without contacting the update server myself).

Comment: @Achim: Windows downloaded a set of updates to install for you in the background, and can offer to install the already downloaded updates offline. But if you left your machine disconnected (or disabled the Windows Update service), and new updates were released, you would not be notified and Windows would have no means of determining this.

Comment: @Billy: that's also what I thought but there must be the information which updates can be installed must be stored somewhere.

Comment: Achim: Well, yeah. Installed updates are listed in Windows Installer's database. But installed and available mean very different things.

Comment: @Achim: Sorry, I misread your comment. No, it isn't installed anywhere. The Windows team doesn't make updates unless they discover a security or reliability problem with a section of code. If they knew about these things in advance, there would never need to be updates in the first place. Windows needs network access in order to determine which updates need to be installed. It can install *already downloaded* installation packages for you offline; but that can be as simple as "look, there are update `.msi`s over here!"

Comment: @Billy: I'm pretty sure the OP just wants to know the results of the last detection.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, the `UpdateCount` REG_DWORD value in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\UAS` appears to contain the number of pending updates.

Since this isn't documented, it might change without warning, but for in-house use it may meet your needs.  On the other hand, depending on your circumstances, you might be better off running WSUS, which includes reporting capabilities.  There's also a WSUS API.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it just seems to work on Windows 7 and not Windows 8 or Vista. Sorry, I should have mentioned that it should work on these systems too.